# Flutter - What's the best practice to create a fixed AppBar during navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In native android development, it is common to use `FragmentTransaction` to create a navigation animation, where the actionBar's position stays fixed (but actionBar's content changed), and the fragment beneath actionBar performs a transition animation (like slide in or out).

To put it simple, the `AppBar` and the body performs different transition animation. In flutter, what is the best practice to create such animation?

Currently I can think of a solution of using a navigation in `Scaffold.body` and using `Stream` + `StreamBuilder` to start `AppBar` redraw. Something like the following code.

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: StreamBuilder<Int>(
        stream: Bloc.of(context).currentFragmentId
        builder: //Some logic to decide which AppBar is appropriate
    ),
    body: Navigator(
        //Navigation between fragments
    ),
)
```

But this is really weird. So is there a best practice to do this? Please let me know!

Comment: But a PageView inside a scaffold can't access the AppBar. And PageView cannot perform hold/slide_up animations.

Comment: PageView will be body of scaffold hence keeping appbar same among all pages- as far as animation goes - you can custom it.

Comment: You can do with GlobalKey for the appbar to update or refresh it and you can use body to show your fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there is currently no answer availble. I'm going to share my solution here, though it is not so elegant.

The solution is to wrap AppBar in a Hero widget. Since Scaffold only takes a PreferedSize widget as an appbar, some customization is required.

```
class HeroAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
//...
  @override
  final Size preferredSize = Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + (bottom?.preferredSize?.height ?? 0.0));
//...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero(
      tag: tag,
      child: AppBar(
        //...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And make sure your Navigator implemented the HeroController. (Default Navigator has already implemented it)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more elegant solution (code-wise) as opposed to @First_Strike:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension HeroAppBar on AppBar {
  PreferredSizeWidget toHero(Object tag) {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: preferredSize,
      child: Hero(tag: tag, child: this),
    );
  }
}
```